# SQL Calculate multiple time differences across a larger time span

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2017

I have an sql back end with a table that is tracking two date columns. The two columns are called OnTime and OffTime. The columns are in the format of small date times. The table is being populated by an arduino micro controller with an accompanying VB form app that will insert a date into the OnTime columns when there is a voltage detected, and populating an OffTime date when the voltage is removed. I need to write an sql query that can gather the total time voltage was detected between each on and off time stamp. The query should look something like

```
SELECT (get times) FROM tableA WHERE OnTime >= @sometime AND OffTime <= @Sometime.
```

This will allow me to run a report on total minutes that voltage was detected. I am familiar with getting time using the `Datediff()` function however I am not sure about summing multiple `datediff()` in this manner.

Sample Data:

```
| ID | OnTime           | OffTime          |
|----|------------------|------------------|
| 1  | 2017-01-01 09:36 | null             |
| 2  | null             | 2017-01-01 10:36 |
| 3  | 2017-01-07 05:36 | null             |
| 4  | null             | 2017-01-07 6:36 |
```

Where Id, ontime, and Offtime are columns.

The desired result would be total time is 120 minutes

Comment: Edit your question and (1) provide the appropriate database tag; (2) provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: _"I am not sure about summing multiple datediff() in this manner. "_ Not sure about what? Did you try it? What went wrong?

Comment: This is SQL Server, right? Edit the tags and add database server (and version).

Comment: @underscore_d I am unsure on how to get date diff between multiple rows and then sum those differences together. Each line will have either an OnTime or an OffTime. I need to sum all the times between those differences whilst using a where clause to run a report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding difference of two time and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697181/sql-query-for-finding-difference-of-two-time-and-sum)

Comment: @AbhilashRavindranCK Ill take a look at that, the only difference I notice right off is that post has both the ontime and off time populated where as I do not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the old-fashioned way of combining pair of rows:

```
WITH testdata (ID, OnTime, OffTime) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2017-01-01 09:36', null UNION
    SELECT 2, null, '2017-01-01 10:36' UNION
    SELECT 3, '2017-01-07 05:36', null UNION
    SELECT 4, null, '2017-01-07 6:36'
), on_off_time AS (
    SELECT a.ID, a.OnTime, MIN(b.OffTime) AS OffTime
    FROM testdata a
    INNER JOIN testdata b ON b.OffTime > a.OnTime
    GROUP BY a.ID, a.OnTime
)
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OnTime, OffTime))
FROM on_off_time
```

Or use the [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function (SQL Server 2012 or later):

```
WITH testdata (ID, OnTime, OffTime) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2017-01-01 09:36', null UNION
    SELECT 2, null, '2017-01-01 10:36' UNION
    SELECT 3, '2017-01-07 05:36', null UNION
    SELECT 4, null, '2017-01-07 6:36'
), on_off_time AS (
    SELECT ID, LAG(OnTime, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(OnTime, OffTime)) AS OnTime, OffTime
    FROM testdata
)
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OnTime, OffTime))
FROM on_off_time
WHERE OffTime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry I miss-read your query -- it will work but is not very fast since the join pulls in all values greater which could be a lot of values.  I like the 2nd one using lag -- that is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the table

```
ID | OnTime             | OffTime
---|--------------------|--------------
  1|2018-02-12 08:00:00 |null
  2|null                |2018-02-12 09:00:00
  3|2018-02-13 07:00:00 |null
  4|null                |2018-02-13 09:00:00
```

You could do the following:

```
WITH Ons AS
(
 SELECT ID,
        ID + 1 AS IDPlusOne,
        OnTime
 FROM Dates
 WHERE NOT OnTime IS NULL 
)
,

Offs AS
(
 SELECT ID,
        OffTime
 FROM Dates
 WHERE NOT OffTime IS NULL
)

SELECT Ons.ID, 
       Offs.ID, 
       DateDiff(MINUTE, Ons.OnTime, Offs.OffTime) as DiffInMinutes 
FROM Ons INNER JOIN Offs ON Ons.IDPlusOne = Offs.ID
```

which results to

```
ID | ID | DiffInMinutes
---|----|---------------
  1|   2|60
  3|   4|120
```

However your design is rather unfortunate as it requires the records to
be strictly sequential. I highly recommend saving both datetimes within the same record

Answer (score 0):

If your entries are always consistent with their ID`s you can use this simple method to get the time between each datapoint:

```
SELECT ID,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Ontime, (SELECT Offtime FROM yourtable t2 where t2.ID = t.ID+1)) AS 'Minutes on, per period'
FROM yourtable t
WHERE Ontime is not null;
```

This you can expand as you like, for example by summarizing like this

```
 SELECT SUM(Minutes) AS 'Total minutes on, all periods'
    FROM (
      SELECT ID,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Ontime, (SELECT Offtime FROM yourtable t2 where t2.ID = t.ID+1)) AS 'Minutes'
      FROM yourtable t
      WHERE Ontime is not null
    ) AS Subtable
```

I made you a fiddle here if you want to try the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9db41/18

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
;WITH tblDateDifference AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, OnTime,OffTime
    FROM tableA
)

SELECT sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cur.OnTime,nxt.OffTime)) AS TotalMinute
FROM tblDateDifference cur,tblDateDifference nxt
WHERE nxt.RowNumber = cur.RowNumber + 1
```

Click here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c4bd/3